# NetworkStream.GetStream() never returns

Tags: c#, sockets, unity-game-engine, tcp

I'm *really* confused. I am able to connect a TCPClient to a tcp server asynchronously. In my callback I now want to start reading some data, but when I go `stream = tcpClient.GetStream();` my program doesn't exactly hang, it just does nothing. It won't go to the next line of the method, but the UI is still running (it's Unity, maybe it is multithreaded or something).

```
public void SetupSocket() {
        try {
            tcpClient = new TcpClient(host, port);
            tcpClient.BeginConnect(host, port, ConnectCallback, tcpClient);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // stuff happens
            return;
        }
    }

private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult result) {
    if (ConnectedToServer != null)
        ConnectedToServer(this, new ServerEventArgs("Connected to server."));

    Debug.Log("Where am I?"); // it does get here

    try {
        stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException e){
        Debug.Log(e); // no exception
    }


    Debug.Log("Hello?"); // never gets here
    BeginReadData();
}


public void BeginReadData() {
    Debug.Log(stream.CanRead); // No log here!
     if (stream.CanRead) {
            stream.BeginRead(tcpStateObject.buffer, 0, tcpStateObject.bufferSize, EndReadData, stream);
    }
}
```

I'm really lost at this point. I can see on my server that I connected, and when I disconnect. I send two messages to the client. It used to work with synchronous sockets, but I wanted async.

Comment: I stream will not return until it gets to the end which only occurs when the TCP connection closes which I don't like doing.  Receiver needs to know when each message if finished.   When using TCP I normally recommend terminating each method using one or combination of the following 3 techniques : 1) AScii : Terminating with a char like '\n'.  2) Ascii or Binary : Adding Bytes Count to beginning of each message. 3) Ascii or Binary : Using fixed length message.  Like Write is 4 bytes while Read is 7 bytes.

Comment: I was using `"<EOF>"` I thought that was standard.

Comment: How do I even check if the stream is done? I can't seem to operate on stream once I go GetStream

Comment: Microsoft Socket classes are really poorly designed.  EOF can only be used with ASCII files and not Binary.  You need two use two network layers.  An application level and a transport layer (which is TCP).  Look at following webpage for samples.  The samples uses Sockets but can be replaced with TCPClient or TCPListener which inherits the socket class : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer

I was connecting twice

```
        tcpClient = new TcpClient(host, port);
        tcpClient.BeginConnect(host, port, ConnectCallback, tcpClient);
```